# how to prepare a string to be inserted into MySQL e.g. add backslash

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a description of a thing that need to be inserted into MySQL. A string can have any character like <'>, <\'>,<\'>:

```
    string=This \'is\' a string
    string=This is a' string
    string=This '\is\' a string
```

C# code:

```
   strDescerption=strDescerption.Trim(new char[] { '\'', '\\' }).Replace("'''", " ").Replace("''", "\"").Replace("'", @"\'").Replace(@"\\'", @"\'");

            MySqlCommand mySqlCommandThing = new MySqlCommand("", mySqlConnection);
            mySqlCommandThing.CommandText = "Insert into table (string) values ("+ strDescerption+")";
            int isInserted = mySqlCommandThing.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If I use them like that I will get MySQL insert error. 
The above examples are the original string, and just adding backslash before ' cant solve the problem. What else can I do in order to preparing this string? I am using C# and MySQL.

Comment: Use [bind parameters](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters)!

Comment: how ur adding it, please show the c# code.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch: could you provide an example? saw the link, couldnt get the point though

Comment: Post your C# and MySQL code please. Or click on the link scroll to the bottom and click C# (the default example is Java).

Comment: `Insert into table (string) values (strDescerption)` is the sql query you use for the insert. We'Re interested to see the C# code you use to execute this query.

Comment: there is nothing fancy in mysql code in C#!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString()`-method

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following.

```
using System.Web;

var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string);
```